# To prove that it is possible to find a prime number q with a primitive root r such that ind(p) is a prime, for a particular prime p.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

**Question:** Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that there exist a prime number $q$ such that for every integer $n$, the number $n^{p}-p$ is not divisible by $q$.

I was trying to solve the above question with an original method using indices and I couldn't proceed after a certain point. My approach is shown below

$\textbf{Approach:}$  The congruence $n^{p}\equiv p\pmod{q}$ can be reduced to
$$p\cdot ind(n)\equiv ind(p) \pmod{q-1}$$
We can do this since every prime has a primitive root. A solution to this congruence exists iff $gcd(ind(n), q-1)|ind(p)$. Thus, if the congruence has no solution for all integers $n$, then it is logical to conclude that $ind(p)$ could be a prime. Hence, I present the following lemma

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ It is possible to find a prime $q$ with a primitive root $r$ such that $ind_{r}(p)$ is a prime number.

It would be a great help if someone could prove or disprove the above Lemma. Thanks a lot for your help!! :)

Comment: I have never heard of "ind". Please define this function.

Comment: A pattern suggests itself if you look at examples.  Try $p=2,3,5,7...$ and look at some small primes $q$.

Comment: ind(x)=k refers to the smallest exponent k such that r^k is congruent to x modulo p, where p is a prime and r is a primitive root of p. Hope this answers ur q @Peter

Comment: @lulu please elaborate

Comment: Just look at examples.  If $p=2$, what is the least $q$ that works?  What about $p=3,5, 7$ and so on?  I think you will spot a pattern rather quickly (and then, of course, you need to prove that it works).  Should stress:  I don't know that the obvious pattern works.  It appears to work in examples.

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Pravimish That definition of $\operatorname{ind}$ depends on the choice of primitive root. But you do not specify a primitive root, except in the very last instance in the lemma.

Comment: it doesnt matter which primitive root we take. Any one of them works, hence it is not necessary to specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ind_r(p)$ is coprime with $q-1$, then $p \equiv r^{ind_r(p)}$ is a primitive root $\bmod q$ (as $ind_r(p)$ is invertible $\bmod q-1$). Conversely, given a prime $q$ for which $p$ is a primitive root, we may pick any prime $i$ coprime with $q - 1$ and obtain a primitive root $r$ for which $ind_r(p) = i$ by $r \equiv p^{i^{-1}}$.

We therefore need to prove that all primes $p$ are primitive roots modulo some prime $q > p$.

Comment: That last might be a little challenging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, though Artin's conjecture is that there is infinitely many $q$s, we want just one.